# Does "Constructor of an abstract class" exists?

Tags: c++

We can not create an object of abstract class. And constructors create new instances of any class which is called as an object.

This is what I know about the constructor, class and object relationship.

Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Does object of abstract class exists? did you try?

Comment: what i have read is abstract class can not have object.

Comment: Write a constructor and see if the compiler accepts it.

Answer (score 4):

Does it exist?

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
public:
    virtual void f() = 0;
    A()
    {
        std::cout << "Yes it does!" << std::endl;
    }
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    void f() {}
};

int main()
{
    B b;
    return 0;
}
```

> Yes it does!

The technical reason is that somebody needs to initialize the members of `A` and that's the job of the constructor. But you can easily reason it as follows:

The inheritance relation is often termed with "is". For example, an object of type `B` is also of type `A`. In other words `B` is a kind of `A`. The constructor of `A` constructs an object of type `A`. But `b` above is also a kind of `A`, so `A` must have a constructor to be able to construct it.

Comment: constructor initializes members of class?? means suppose i have a class A { int x;}; and if in the main() function if i create object of class A,  A b;  will x become zero? or remain unintialized?

Comment: @Priyanka: remain uninitialized, the constructor's **job** is to initialize the members, but it's **your** responsibility to ensure it does its job.

Answer (score 2):

Yes! It has to exist, since constructors of any child class make a call to the base constructor. (This is the simplest way to explain it)

Answer (score 1):

> Does “Constructor of an abstract class” exists?

Let's say that there can be an abstract class constructor. Just like any other class. By default (if you don't declare a "custom" constructor or you don't have member objects that have no default constructor) there are two implicitly defined: the *default constructor* and the *copy constructor*.

So in a declaration like this:

```
struct abstract_class {
    virtual void func() = 0;
}
```

you still have constructors.

---

> We can not create an object of abstract class.

Yes. For the most common definition of *abstract class*, that is true. If a class does have *pure virtual* functions, it is considered to be an *abstract class* and of course it cannot be instantiated.

---

> And constructors create new instances of any class which is called as an object.

I'd rephrase that to: You construct objects of a class type via their constructor. And yes, in C++, an *object* is (from §1.8/1):

> An object is a region of storage.

And that's that. For example:

```
int x = 0;
```

is an object too. An *object* does not necessarily mean a class type.

Comment: This answer has some patience +1

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes can contain member variables and to initialize those member variables Abstract classes need constructor.